# Express over Node.js - TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm building my first node/express app and am following [this tut](https://blog.lucius.digital/headless-drupal-node-js-part-3-3-express-js-and-drupal-api-integration-97f62de2d255).

I am at a point where I am trying to get all JSON data and put it in an array to be sent to the template and rendered. When I try to run the app via CLI, I get the following error:

[image: CLI error]

**Directory Structure**

[image: directory structure for app]

**The data output at the var blogsurlall location**

[image: JSON data output]

**hellotest.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require("request");
var blogsurlall = "https://[JSON export URL location configured in a Drupal 8 view]";

app.set('view engine','ejs');

var server = app.listen (2000, function(){ console.log('Waiting for you on port 2000'); });

/* Get all global blogs data */
request({
    url: blogsurlall,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        blogsdata_all = body;
    }

    // Create blogs array for footer.
    var blogs = [];

    // Fill up the array with blogs.
    blogsdata_all.blogs.forEach(function(item){
        blogs = blogs.concat(item);
    });

    app.locals.blogsdata = blogs;
});

app.use('/', routes);
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = express.Router();

routes.get('/', function(req, res){ res.render('default',{title: 'Home', body: 'blogsdata'}); });

routes.get('/about-us', function(req, res){ res.send('<h1>Lucius Websystems</h1>Amsterdam, The Netherlands'); });

routes.get('/about/:name?', function(req, res){ var name = req.params.name; res.send('<h1>' +name +'</h1>About text'); });

/* GET Blog detail page. */
routes.get('/blog/:blogid', function(req, res, next) {

    // Place json data in a var.
    var blogsdata = req.app.locals.blogsdata;

    // Create array.
    var blogItem = [];

    // Check and build current URL
    var currentURL = '/blog/' + req.params.blogid;

    // Lop through json data and pick correct blog-item based on current URL.
    blogsdata.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item.title == currentURL) {
            blogItem = item;
        }
    });

    if (blogItem.length == 0) {
        // Render the 404 page.
        res.render('404', {
            title: '404',
            body: '404'
        });

    } else {
        // Render the blog page.
        res.render('blog-detail', {
            blog: blogItem
        });
    }

});

module.exports = routes;
```

From the CLI error, it appears no blog data is even returned to be read into the array.

I have carefully gone through the tutorial several times and I think there are steps that may be implied that I am missing.

Can someone please help me understand how to get the blog data so that it can be read into the array and output to my template?

Also open to troubleshooting suggestions in comments.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: That means that `blogsdata_all.blogs` likely isn't the array that you think it is. Have you checked what it actually is?

Answer (score 0):

The error is raising in this line:

```
blogsdata_all.blogs.forEach(function(item){
```

As the error says, blogs is undefined. 
If there is an error in the request or status code isn't 200, the body is not assigned to the variable, but you are not finishing the execution, so the variable in that case would be undefined.
Other possible problem is the json received doesn't have blogs as key of the body.
Check this both things and let us know if you found the problem